# Cant pass url param to Objcet using [FromRoute] in APS.NET Core

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, controller

I learn ASP.NET Core and have this React app that works ok except for that I can make a Crud call to the ASP.NET `Controller` but the url query string cant be mapped to Object using the `[FromRoute]`

I think I do something wrong, 
Please advice looking at the picture:

[image]

Comment: First off, you are supposed to post the  code as text, not as an image, or else it is note searchable. Second, now would be a good time to look up what the different attributes does, e.g. `[FromRoute]`, using the docs., as it state very clear what it does. Do note, you are supposed to do a proper research before posting, and it appears you haven't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[FromRoute]` Means you'll attempt to get it from the route, not the query `/{title}/{author}/{genre}/{price}`.

You have to use `[FromQuery]` to get the data from query: `?title=aa&author=bb...`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this to see if it work

```
public IActionResult Books([FromQuery]BookModel model)
```